# Is it safe to add index in MySQL table that has 3410114 row?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have some MySQL table that 3410114 row currently. I want to add index to the 'created_at' datetime column. Is is safe to run this? It's on our production server.

I asked chatgpt, and he said it's safe. but I was not sure.

[image]

Comment: You might also try asking at [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *"Is is safe [...]? It's on our production server."* The answer is often : No. Was it tested in another environment first?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? What are you concerned might happen that is not safe?

Comment: @Cid No I didn't test. And not possible to test. So that' why I asked someone who has done it. Have you?

Comment: @JinLim: *"And not possible to test."* - Why on Earth not?  It seems vastly more likely that "not possible to test" really means "not **worth the effort** to test", which drastically changes the already highly subjective scope of "is it safe".  If it doesn't matter enough to test it, then it doesn't really matter much at all.

Comment: "Safe"??  No data will be lost.  However, there _may_ be an impact (eg, slowdown) on database activity until the ALTER finishes.

Answer (score 0):

An index needs space in storage.
Check if there is sufficient free disk space available.
Overall server performance may be impacted while the index is being created.

If you can, test it in your staging environment first, under load.
Row counts in the single-digit millions are not really that much to worry about in any reasonably recent environment.

There is one popular approach which creates an empty table based on the same schema as the table to be indexed, then creates the index, and then moves the data. I'd vote against that in a production environment due to transactional/data integrity concerns - unless you can allocate a maintenance downtime. Also, it is sometimes not possible, for instance when there is a schema-bound view on top.